# Xcode Cloud cannot detect all of local swift package added as submodules

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager, xcode-cloud

I have created many Swift packages as Git submodules to share among my projects.

I have decided to use Xcode Cloud to build my application instead of Fastlane. However, Xcode Cloud cannot detect the full list of Swift packages added as submodules in my project. As a result, it fails at the clone step.

I have a `.gitmodules` file in root folder of project.

```
[submodule "Packages/CommonKitUI"]
    path = Packages/CommonKitUI
    url = git@github.com:myOrgs/CommonKitUI.git
[submodule "Packages/FoundationX"]
    path = Packages/FoundationX
    url = git@github.com:myOrgs/FoundationX.git
...
```

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try to open appstoreconnect.apple.com with your account

and go to Xcode Cloud -> Settings -> Repositories

under "Additional Repositories"

you may find those repository with grant access button next to them and you need to grant access to those repositories.